# Using CDN for putting css of react application

Tags: css, reactjs, cdn, stylus

I have been reading about leveraging cdn to boost the speed of web application. I am developing a react application and I am using stylus for css. My current structure of project is something like this: Each component or page has it's own seperate local stylus file. So this way I am trying to keep the syles isolated for each component so that it is easy to maintain. But mostly all the stylus files has around 1000 lines of code which is common for all the stylus files. This brings down the speed of my application while it loads. I am thinking of putting the css on cdn. This way it will be faster I am assuming. How can I do it with my present project structure?

Right now I include stylus like this in each component

```
import c from "./reviews.styl"

 render() {

        return (
            <div className={c.container}>
```

If I create a seperate css file as sugegsted in answer to include all the common css, how will I say to each component to use that common.css file. Each component is already using the imported stylus file like I shown above

Comment: Just import the common CSS in the index JS file of your App (the uppermost component) in the hierarchy, and it will pass those styles down to its children automatically.

e.g.

`index.js`
`import "../styles/common.css";`

`homepage.js`
`<div className="some common style"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

You have a few ways here...

1. In the constructor you can append a link tag to the head
2. In componentWillMount you can append a link tag to the head

e.g.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild('<link rel=stylesheet href=mycdn.com/mystylesheet.css />');
```

I'm not saying moving your CSS to a CDN is a good solution, but this is how you'd accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of a CDN is that your static web assets are deployed across the world on multiple servers and your users can easily retrieve quick copies of these assets.  In the case where you are using a file like jquery-x.js, users may already have retrieved the file from the CDN for another website and even on the first page load, they can use a cached copy.

Your biggest issue is the duplication of CSS code throughout each component's style page and that can be overcome by just creating a generic style sheet with the common styles (say "common.css") and then including it in each component.  You don't have to use a CDN to achieve this and you can investigate CDNs after you first get rid of the duplicate CSS as another way to speed up your page load.